The set of all ellipsoids $\mathcal{E}(A)$ contained in a bounded open set $A$ is compact
We call $A\subset\Bbb R^d$ a convex body if $A$ is a convex, non-empty, open, and bounded. The open unit ball in $\Bbb R^d$ is denoted by $B_d$. In Tao-Vu's book, they say:

Define an ellipsoid to be any set $E$ of the form $E = L(B_d) + x_0$, where $B_d$ is the unit ball, $x_0 ∈ \Bbb R^d$, and $L$ is a (possibly degenerate) linear transformation in $\Bbb R^d$; we allow the ellipsoid to be degenerate for compactness reasons. Since $A$ is open and bounded, it is easy to see that the set of all ellipsoids $E$ contained in $A$ is a compact set (with respect to the usual topology on $L$ and $x_0$.)

It seems the convexity assumption on $A$ is not required to show the compactness of the set of ellipsoids. The set can be written explicitly as
$$\mathcal E(A) = \{E = L(B_d) + x_0: L:\Bbb R^d \to \Bbb R^d \text{ linear, }x_0 \in \Bbb R^d, E \subset A\}.$$
In particular, we can identify every ellipsoid $L(B_d) + x_0$ with a tuple $(L,x_0)$, so $$\mathcal E(A) \subset M_d(\Bbb R) \times \Bbb R^d,$$
and we want to show that $\mathcal E(A)$ is compact with respect to the topology on $M_d(\Bbb R) \times \Bbb R^d$. How should this argument go? I tried a sequential argument, with ellipsoids $\{(L_n,x_n)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ contained in $A$, but I'm not sure how to use the compactness of $\overline{A}$ to extract a convergent subsequence. Thank you!

I guess in the quote instead on "topology on $L$ and $x_0$" should be "topology on $M_d(\Bbb R) \times \Bbb R^d$".

My general intuition of a general topologist suggests that usually there is no compactness based on the open sets. The required claim is wrong too. For instance, let $d=1$ and $A=B_1$. For each natural $n$ let $L_n(x)=x/n$ for each $x\in\mathbb R$ and $x_n=1-1/n$, so $L_n(B_1)+x_n\subset A$.
The sequence $(L_n,x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges in $M_d(\mathbb R)\times\mathbb R$ to $(L_0,1)$, where $L_0$ is the zero matrix. But $L_0(B_1)+1=\{1\}\not\subset A$.

That is absolutely correct but I've seen the word "compact" being used instead of the correct "pre-compact" so many times that I wonder if it is just one more instance of the same standard blunder. Unfortunately, the only way to find out is to read the passages following the quoted one and they have not been provided...
